# Why was my spam flag declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880585/android-fragmentactivity-with-listview-from-json-data/24544830#24544830) as a spam but it was declined with the below reason:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it

So now my question, if it's declined then why Community ♦ have deleted this answer. My point is that at one point of time moderator says they haven't found any evidence to support it and at another side, he/she has deleted.

[image]

Comment: This isn't really a piece of advertising or even nonsensical blabbering, is it?

Comment: Community account deleted the answer because the whole account has been Destroyed, meaning all its posts deleted by automatic process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The flag was declined because, well, let's take a look:

[image]

Now, granted, I skipped "Advertising 101" but I don't see how the post you link to is advertisement. Not an answer, sure, and that's why it should be deleted. (Though [as @ShadowWizard said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235015/why-was-my-spam-flag-declined#comment772763_235015) in the comments, the whole account is gone, which most likely took the answer with it) But it's not spam. Please don't use spam flags for "bad content". Use it for actual spam.

Comment: To be fair, there seems to be varying interpretations of what can and can't be flagged as spam/offensive.  It may be a culture shift, depending on which site you're on.